# Registration error in Laravel version5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am creating offline project in college, when i do Registration, data is successfully store but give me a error, How can i remove this error and give a message successfully registered
[This is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdbLd.jpg)
**error is here** :

> `class\Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification
>   does not exist`

Comment: this class doesn't exist SendEmailVerificationNotification make sure you class name is correct

Comment: so what can i do for remove that error? -@SalmanZafar

Comment: remove this class SendEmailVerificationNotification from your registration controller

Comment: @Kinnari Prajapati Can you Please display your current insert code.

Comment: SendEmailVerificationNotification This class doesn't exist in registration controller -@SalmanZafar

Comment: Double check to be sure your class name is correct in your `SendEmailVerificationNotification.php`. You could have a file called `SendEmailVerificationNotification` but your class name is named differently. This happens a lot when you duplicate a file and forget to change the class name.

Comment: I can not show you code bcoz my college not allow net, I clicked error pic which i update in question -@AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Comment: @Kinnari Prajapati  Can you Please this pic share with us.

Comment: yes updated -@AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Answer (score 0):

i think,need to call SendEmailVerificationNotification listener path in your controller.

```
use App\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
```

Answer (score -5):

i had the same problem while using laravel 5.6 this is how i solved it.

1. go to **vendors** forder
2. locate Auth by following this path "**framework/src/Illuminate/Auth**"
3. create a folder call it **Listeners** if that folder doesnt exist.
4. in that folder create a php file call it
   **SendEmailVerificationNotification.php**
5. copy and paste the following code.

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Illuminate\Auth\Listeners;
   use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
   class SendEmailVerificationNotification
   {
   /**
    * Handle the event.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered  $event
    * @return void
    */
     public function handle(Registered $event)
     {
       if ($event->user instanceof MustVerifyEmail && ! $event->user- 
             >hasVerifiedEmail()) {
           $event->user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
            }
        }
     }
   ```

Comment: it's not a good practice to change external repositories directly. if the only way to solve the problem is to change external source codes it's better to fork them and use your instance.

Comment: you should never make any change in the vendors folder